# How to reformat nested array of data?

Tags: javascript

> I am trying to reformat this array

```
const array =[
        [
            {name: 'John', score: 78},
            {name: 'Peter', score: 88}
        ],
        [
            {name: 'John', score: 98},
            {name: 'Peter', score: 80}
        ]
        
    ]
```

Into this

> newArray = [['John', 78, 98], ['Peter', 88, 80]]

All I can do is just like this

```
let name = []
    let score = []


    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        const detail = array[i]
        
        for (var j = 0; j < detail.length; j++) {
                name.push(detail[j].name)
                        
        }

        for (var j = 0; j < detail.length; j++) {
                scoreArray = detail[j].score
                score.push(scoreArray)
                        
        }           
    }

    const newArray= name.concat(score)
```

And give me the result

```
["John", "Peter", "John", "Peter", 78, 88, 98, 80]
```

Comment: [_"group by"_](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+array+of+objects+group+by+site%3Astackoverflow.com) name (which will most likely get you something like `"John": [ ... ]`), then use `Object.entries()` and `Array.flat()`

Comment: Are you certain this is the output you want? `[['John', 78, 98], ['Peter', 88, 80]]`.

Comment: Yes, I use Grid.js https://gridjs.io/docs/integrations/react and the data format is just like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const array =[
        [
            {name: 'John', score: 78},
            {name: 'Peter', score: 88}
        ],
        [
            {name: 'John', score: 98},
            {name: 'Peter', score: 80}
        ]
        
    ]

// get the unique names
const names = [...new Set(...array.reduce((acc, item) => {
    return [...acc, item.map(i => [i.name])]
}, []))]

// add the scores next to the names
array.flat().forEach((el) => {
   names.forEach(([name], index) => {
     if (el.name === name) {
       names[index].push(el.score)
     }
   })
})

console.log(names)
```

But I think you better do it this way:

```js
const array =[
        [
            {name: 'John', score: 78},
            {name: 'Peter', score: 88}
        ],
        [
            {name: 'John', score: 98},
            {name: 'Peter', score: 80}
        ]
        
    ]

const result = [...new Set(...array.reduce((acc, item) => {
    return [...acc, item.map(i => ({name: i.name, scores: []}))]
}, []))]


// add the scores next to the names
array.flat().forEach((el) => {
   result.forEach(({name, scores}, index) => {
     if (el.name === name) {
       scores.push(el.score)
     }
   })
})

console.log(result)
```

And store the names and scores to their own keys.